# What does this blue dot in the Dock in Mojave mean?

Tags: mojave, dock

I have this pale blue dot above Firefox (I have seen in on other apps also.)

I have only noticed this in Mojave.

What does it mean?

My Dock is in the vertical position.

[image: Pale blue dot]

Here is is in the horizontal position:

[image: Pale blue dot, horizontal]

More info from Dock:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.dock.plist | grep "file-label"
                "file-label" = Siri;
                "file-label" = Launchpad;
                "file-label" = Safari;
                "file-label" = Mail;
                "file-label" = Contacts;
                "file-label" = Notes;
                "file-label" = Reminders;
                "file-label" = Maps;
                "file-label" = Photos;
                "file-label" = Messages;
                "file-label" = FaceTime;
                "file-label" = Pages;
                "file-label" = Numbers;
                "file-label" = Keynote;
                "file-label" = News;
                "file-label" = iTunes;
                "file-label" = Books;
                "file-label" = "App Store";
                "file-label" = "System Preferences";
                "file-label" = iTerm;
                "file-label" = Downloads;
                "file-label" = "Workspace ONE Intelligent Hub";
                "file-label" = "Activity Monitor";
                "file-label" = Firefox;
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you position the Dock to the bottom of the screen and share a screenshot with that view too?

Comment: Can you clarify for me if you've ever seen more than one instance of this icon at the same time?

Comment: @Monomeeth, I don't believe so, but I have only really noticed it today.

Comment: That’s  a teeny docker icon in you dock! Impressive

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've seen instances in the past when certain app icons appear incredibly small in the Dock, to the point that clicking on them does nothing. The icon in your screenshot looks very similar to the Twitter icon, so if you're a Twitter user it could be that.

Regardless, I would start with restarting the Dock as a first step. To do this:

1. Now open Terminal (usually located in Applications > Utilities)
2. Enter this command `killall Dock`
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Once you've done that, use your Mac for long enough to know if this has resolved the issue. If it hasn't, then you can do a reset **and** restart of your Dock as follows.<sup>1</sup>

To reset and restart the Dock, follow these steps:

1. Go to Finder
2. Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
3. Now go to the Go menu
4. Select the Library option to open the User's *Library* folder. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now.
5. Go to the Preferences folder (i.e. within the Library folder)
6. Find and move the **com.apple.dock.plist** file to the Trash
7. Now open Terminal (usually located in Applications > Utilities)
8. Enter this command `killall Dock`
9. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Once you've done that, use your Mac for long enough to know if this has resolved the issue.

<sup>1. **IMPORTANT:** After doing this you will need to re-add any non-default icons (i.e. apps) that you've added to the Dock. Before proceeding you may want to take some notes (or a screenshot of your Dock) as a reminder of what you had there previously.</sup>

Comment: @tahsmith can also share the screenshot of the app switcher to help establish this theory.

Comment: I have to disagree by starting with a destructive process! Investigate a bit first by looking at the output of e.g. `defaults read com.apple.dock.plist | grep "file-label"` and see the names of the apps that are there. See what's listed between Activity Monitor and Firefox.

Comment: @user3439894, Updated my Q with that info. There is nothing between them.

Comment: @NimeshNeema there are no Icons in the app switcher which are not in the Dock

Comment: @tahsmith,  If you do just `killall Dock` in Terminal, is the blue dot still there?

Comment: @user3439894 Nope, it's gone. :S

Comment: This was the issue in the end. But I did not actually go through these steps.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the feedback. Based on this and the OP's experience, I've updated my answer. :)

Comment: One should not have to use the `-KILL` _signal_, `killall Dock` should be all that's necessary.